# Как победить contentscript.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')

Tags: javascript

Есть простейший код:

```
<body>
    <h1>foo</h1>
    <script>
      let foo = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
      function cons() {
        console.log(foo);
      }
      foo.onclick = cons;
    </script>
  </body>
```

Клик на h1 не работает, в консоли ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector'). Почему null не пойму. Через консоль к переменной foo обратиться могу.

Comment: В приведённом коде вообще нет `querySelector`.

Comment: Всё так. querySelector нет, а ошибка есть: https://i.postimg.cc/vH67LQxr/err.jpg

Comment: @CEZAR, там вообще код расширения браузерного, который к сайту не имеет ни малейшего отношения. Как и приведённая ошибка. А ответ правильный тебе дали - прими его.

Comment: @SwaD, не его случай...

Answer (score 1):

При использовании getElementsByClassName вы получаете не елемент, а HTML коллекцию https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Решить проблему можно так:

```js
const foo = document.getElementById('title');
function cons() {
    console.log(foo);
}
foo.onclick = cons
```

```html
<h1 id="title">foo</h1>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш совет помог обратиться к элементу, но ошибка в консоли осталась, и реагирует на любое движение мыши: https://i.postimg.cc/vH67LQxr/err.jpg

Comment: У меня в коде вообще нету querySelector. Ошибка где-то у Вас в коде. Попробуйте закомментировать весь остальной код и проверьте. Вы изначально спрашивали про querySelector, хотя в приведенном коде его нету.

Comment: В том и дело, что я привёл весть код на странице. Других строк там нет... А ошибка есть.

Comment: Значит где-то в другом месте есть. Возможно где-то в HTML встроен скрипт который и выдает эту ошибку.

Comment: ИМХО что-то на стороне браузера происходит. В коде всё проще некуда. Весь код  в <body>я приложил. В <head> стандартный шаблон IDE по "!" + tab
Яндекс-браузер тоже выдаёт ошибку, но другую 
https://i.postimg.cc/y6wJX0Hd/err.jpg

Comment: А в ФФ вообще ошибки нет:  https://i.postimg.cc/Z51ZXxwB/err.jpg

Comment: Попробуйте в режиме 'инкогнито', возможно ошибка из-за какого-то расширения.

Comment: Действительно, в режиме 'инкогнито' ошибки нет. Большое спасибо!